# Why does setting the readline() function equal to itself inside a while loop move on to the next line?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand a piece of code someone else has written in python. Why does `line = f.readline()` inside the `while` loop make it so that all the lines in the textfile1 get printed?

When you delete the `line = f.read.readline()` inside the while loop only the first line gets printed.

```py
f = open("textfile1.txt", "r")

line = f.readline()
while line:
    print (line)
    line = f.readline()
```

I expect the `while` loop to keep running on the first line. since you set line equal to itself.

Comment: `f.readline()` is a method call that returns the next line of `f`, so there is nothing strange here.

Comment: Do lines = f.readlines() and after for line in lines

Comment: It's not equal to itself, both time you assign the result of the `f.readline()` call which itself changes (because the `f` object maintains a cursor in the file and reads from there, incrementing it as it reads)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f.readline()` returns the *next line* of the file when called. So it's not setting it equal to itself, it's setting `line` to the next line of the file. See the doc for `readline` at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: `f.readline() ` reads a line and move the cursor to the next position (next line), therefore, the next `f.readline()` will read the next line